# join tables to display posts of people who I follow

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want to display the posts of people who I follow

The 3 tables I have are:

Users:

```
+---------+------+
| id_user | name | last_logout
+---------+------+
|       1 | A    | 22-02-2018 00:00:10
|       2 | B    |
|       3 | C    |
|       4 | D    |
|       5 | E    |
+---------+------+
```

Community:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| id_follower | id_followed |
+-------------+-------------+
|           1 |           2 |
|           1 |           3 |
|           1 |           5 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Posts:

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+
| id_post | id_user_post |     post      |  date
+---------+--------------+---------------+
|       1 |            2 | hi            |
|       2 |            3 | hello         |
|       3 |            5 | hey you       | 
|       4 |            4 | come on       |
|       5 |            5 | where are you | 22-02-2018 00:01:00
+---------+--------------+---------------+
```

I'm using the following code but it doesn't return anything

```
SELECT u.name AS n
    ,p.post AS t
FROM community AS c
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id_user = c.id_followed
LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON c.id_followed = p.id_user_post
WHERE u.id_follower = 1
```

Comment: who you follow should be `inner join` on Users and `left join` on post

Comment: it retrieve some other records.

Comment: For starters, the `users` table , which you have aliased as `u`, doesn't have a `id_follower` column so your WHERE clause isn't valid. I'm surprised that you don't get an error rather than just getting no records. What DBMS are you using? FYI, when asking SQL questions please always tag the relevant DBMS, as it can make a big difference to the correct answer.

Comment: It was a typing mistake not part of the code.

Comment: I've updated the question due to a new doubt. thank you.

Comment: MySql & php only

Comment: @Jean Please roll back your **changes** and ask a new question. You can leave this original question as it may be helpful to future visitors. The question and answer pairing does not make sense when a future visitor comes to this page and the question has been changed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Users.id_follower` does not exist, so that is why you get nothing, in fact you are likely getting an error (*Invalid column name 'id_follower'.*).

Use `Community.id_follower` instead. I would also recommend using more descriptive column names (like 'username' and 'comment')

*For the pure reason of answering your specific question, I have used 'n' and 't' in the query.*

```
SELECT u.name as n, p.post as t
FROM Community c
LEFT JOIN Users u ON c.id_followed = u.id_user
LEFT JOIN Posts p ON c.id_followed = p.id_user_post
WHERE c.id_follower = 1
```

---

Test:

```
;WITH USERS AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,'A'),
                 (2,'B'),
                 (3,'C'),
                 (4,'D'),
                 (5,'E')) U(id_user, name))
, Community AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,2),
                 (1,3),
                 (1,5)) C(id_follower, id_followed))
, posts AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,2,'hi'),
                 (2,3,'hello'),
                 (3,5,'hey you'),
                 (4,4,'come on'),
                 (5,5,'where are you')) P(id_post, id_user_post, post))                


SELECT u.name as n, p.post as t
FROM Community c
LEFT JOIN Users u ON c.id_followed = u.id_user
LEFT JOIN Posts p ON c.id_followed = p.id_user_post
WHERE c.id_follower = 1
```

[image]

Comment: My bad. Im going to check it out. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question due to a related doubt, thank you